# syntax error in conditional expression

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a script where I am using the combination of logical 'OR' and logical 'AND' statement. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the value of a"
read $a
echo "Enter the value of b"
read $b
if

[[ $a != STARTED && $b == STARTED ] || [ $b != STARTED && $a == STARTED ]]; then

echo "Either of the JVMs is not yet up, so lets wait for some more time"

i=$(($i+1))
sleep 1s

fi
```

and getting the following error while executing it:

```
line 13: syntax error in conditional expression
line 13: syntax error near `]'
line 13: `[[ $a != STARTED && $b == STARTED ] || [ $b != STARTED && $a == STARTED ]]; then'
```

I am using bash shell. Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: single brace is old style of shell programming and you have to use -o and -a for OR and AND.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mismatched `[[` with `]`. `[[` should always be closed with `]]` and `[` with `]`. Use:

```
if [[ $a != STARTED && $b == STARTED ]] || [[ $b != STARTED && $a == STARTED ]]; then
```

Better yet, since you are using `[[` anyway:

```
if [[ ($a != STARTED && $b == STARTED) || ($b != STARTED && $a == STARTED) ]]; then
```

The other mistake, which I didn't notice until formatting was applied, is that you're doing:

```
read $a
read $b
```

You should be doing:

```
read a
read b
```

With the first form, `$a` and `$b` are replaced by the shell with their contents, so if you hadn't set them before this line, the final command would be:

```
read
```

(in which case the value read would be stored in the `REPLY` variable.) And if you had set `a` to something  (like `a="blah blah"`), it would look like:

```
read blah blah
```

Comment: i have used both the statements mentioned but after providing the values of a and b respectively, it is not taking me to the if condition even if the condition satisfies.

Comment: @SudevJash see update.

Comment: Thanks a lot Muru... Making the required changes worked as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
[[ $a != STARTED && $b == STARTED ] || [ $b != STARTED && $a == STARTED ]]; then
```

I would use:

```
if [ $a != STARTED && $b == STARTED ] || [ $b != STARTED && $a == STARTED ]; then
```

Comment: I m getting the error as :                    blserver1.sh: line 11: [: missing `]'
blserver1.sh: line 11: [: missing `]'

Comment: Recommending `[` over `[[` in a bash script is a retrograde step; and if you are, you must [quote your variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29)...

Comment: And is `&&` supported in `[`?

Comment: Thanks jasonwryan and Michael... i used quotes and it is working fine now...  if [[ "$a" != "STARTED" && "$b" == "STARTED" ]] || [[ "$b" != "STARTED" && "$a" == "STARTED" ]]; then

Comment: @SudevJash You don't need the quotes in `[[` (although they are not harmful): see the link I posted above...

Comment: As for me a little bit shorter `[ "$a" != "$b" ] && [[ "$a$b" =~ "STARTED" ]]`. Or portable variant `[ "$a" = "STARTED" -o "$b" = "STARTED" ] && [ "$a" != "$b" ]` but more shorter `x="STARTED" ; [ "$a" = "$x" -o "$b" = "$x" ] && [ "$a" != "$b" ]`

Comment: This isn't syntactically correct. Did you mean to use double brackets instead of single brackets? That's pretty important, given that this is the topic of the question.

Comment: @Gilles Please show example where is syntactically incorrection.

Comment: @Costas These are four simple commands, separated by the operators `&&`, `||` and `&&`. The first command is `[ $a != STARTED`, which is a syntax error for `[` (“missing ]”). The second command is `$b == STARTED`, which could do anything depending on the value of `b`.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for reply. Now I see that you mean answer's code and do not relay to my comment's code. You are absolutelly right - with single brackets `-a` and `-o` should be used instead of `||` and `&&`